# GUIText in Unity 5 (Need an alternative)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, richtext, gameobject, guitext

I've been following a tutorial on how to make a timer on YouTube but I am now stuck because of the `GUIText` problem in Unity 5. This is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class Timer : MonoBehaviour {

    public float Seconds = 59;
    public float Minutes = 0;

    void Update() {

        if (Seconds <= 0) {

            Seconds = 59;
            if (Minutes > 1) {

                Minutes--;

            } else {

                Minutes = 0;
                Seconds = 0;
                //This makes the guiText show the time as X:XX. ToString.("f0") formats it so there is no decimal place.
                GameObject.Find("TimerText").GUIText.text = Minutes.ToString("f0") + ":0" + Seconds.ToString("f0");

            }

        } else {

            Seconds -= Time.deltaTime;

        }

        //These lines will make sure that the time is shown as X:XX and not X:XX.XXXXXX
        if(Mathf.Round(Seconds) <= 9) {

            GameObject.Find("TimerText").GUIText.text = Minutes.ToString("f0") + ":0" + Seconds.ToString("f0");

        } else {

            GameObject.Find("TimerText").GUIText.text = Minutes.ToString("f0") + ":" + Seconds.ToString("f0");

        }

    }

}
```

The problem is with the `GUIText`.

> error CS1061: Type 'UnityEngine.GameObject' does not contain a
>   definition for 'GUIText' and no extension method 'GUIText' of type
>   'UnityEngine.GameObject' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

What can I do to make the timer show in my game without the `GUIText`?

Comment: This link *might* help: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/853405/gui-text-is-absent-in-unity-46.html

Comment: Please Use `Unity3d` tag instead of `unity` tag

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using Unity.UI ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing `GameObject.Find("TimerText").GUIText.text`, you can rewrite it using `GetComponent(string)` method, which is the right way:

```
GameObject.Find("TimerText").GetComponent<GUIText>().text = 
    Minutes.ToString("f0") + ":0" + Seconds.ToString("f0");
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I have no errors! :) Just need to figure out how to get the text in "GUI text" to be visible.

Answer (score 1):

Simply select your Gameobject that you assigned this code to it and in `Inspector` view click on `Add Component` and add `GUI Text` component to it.
don't forget to set the Font for it

Comment: Can't get the GUI Text component to be visible with any text.

Comment: Make sure you set font to something and font size isn't 0

Comment: I tried, but I think there might be other things that disrupt it. Anyway, thanks! :)